# android:layout_below not properly working

Tags: android

I have a `RelativeLayout` with three views. Both `TextViews` should be to right of the `ImageView` and the seconds one should be below the first `TextView`.

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#bdbdbd"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/default_avatar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
        android:text="Chris"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/university"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/username"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
        android:text="Oxford"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Result: [image]

After removing `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` from the first TextView, everything works as expected (except that it's not vertical).
[image]

**Why is this and how can I make the first `TextView` vertical centered?**

Comment: I just want the first one to be centered vertically and the second one should go below. Centering both TextViews would look like the first screen (which is useless).

Comment: Did you try adding layout_below="@id/username" to the second TextView?

Comment: I have? See code please.

Comment: Sorry. I missed it. What about adding layout_alignLeft="username" removing toRightOf ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason the RelativeLayout's height param is giving the problem. Try setting it to 94dp (64 of the image + 15 of bottom padding + 15 of top padding). This should solve the problem

Comment: I think its really bad practice, just to relay on paddings and margins because when you have different screen sizes it might seem correct.

Answer (score 2):

@f. de is right. The problem is `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, as the height of relative layout is determined my it's content setting it's content to vertically center based on it's height wont work. You need to set this to match_parent or to  a fixed value.

Answer (score 2):

You also could wrap your data, in your case Name and University inside another `RelativeLayout` or any other `ViewGroup` and make it to align center.

Like that

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#bdbdbd"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/default_avatar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/avatar"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chris"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/university"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/username"
            android:text="Oxford"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This makes sense in order to group related views (TextViews) and also it produces better result because whole container is aligned center, in your initial example Name view is centered vertically but other view is below it and it makes it to look not as good as it will in case of container where baseline is vetical center of container.

Answer (score 0):

Since trying to place both TextViews center vertical, they overlap. Use the padding attribute for the advantage.
So to align them as required, use this code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#bdbdbd"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/avatar"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/default_avatar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
    android:text="Chris"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/university"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/username"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:text="Oxford"
    android:textSize="13sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I wish this solves your problem...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your RelativeLayout's height attribute,
if you change it to "match_parent" then it will work the way you wanted.

Or

you can make another Relativelayout in your main RelativeLayout who's height is "match_parent". After doing so you can place everything at any place without any problem.